# I have got the following error while converting my existing code to swift 3. How can I rectify this issue?

Tags: iphone, json, swift3

```
let strData: NSDictionary! = (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myResponseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
```

Error:

> Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type '(with: NSMutableData!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions)'

Comment: declare myResponseData as NSData

Comment: The issue still persist.

Comment: `(myResponseData as Data)`... On another note, excessive use of `!` will  probably bite you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
let strData = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myResponseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
```